# Is there a way I can animate a bezier curve attached to two objects?

Tags: animation, armature, bezier-curves

Let me just start off by saying this is my first time working with armatures, vertex groups, hooks, and curves. I have watched many tutorial videos, read a few blogs but none of them have helped me accomplish what I want to accomplish. Basically, I want this cylindrical object to hang from the box-shaped object, I want them to be connected by a chord, and I want to be able to animate them all moving together. For example, if I move the box to the right, the chord should stay the SAME LENGTH, and the cylindrical piece should just dangle from it. Then, if I want to lower the cylinder, the chord should stretch and stay attached to the top of it, as well as stay attached to the box above.

The box and the cylinder are both parented to their own armatures. The bezier curve has two endpoints that are hooked to empty objects, and these empties are also parented to the aforementioned armatures. I just tried to animate them all using the armatures but I didn't get the results I wanted. I inserted a keyframe when the curve was very short in length on frame 0. I then tried to move the box to the right and drag the curve and the cylinder along with it and then extend the curve once the box stopped. But the box ended up being stationary and the cable stayed pretty much the same length in the end result. I have included screen shots containing all the relevant information I think someone would need to help identify the problem. I really hope somebody can help because I've been struggling with this for 2 weeks. If you need more info please tell me what you'd like to see specifically.
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: if you don't plan to use physics (?) you could try Spline IK, see my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116124/how-to-rig-a-cartoon-style-hose-limb-cartoon-arm/116128

Comment: What kind of physics? Like softbodies? I tried that at one point and the curve kinda bounced between the two objects

Comment: you could use Cloth but I'm not sure you want physics, you need to decide, if you want physics you need to pin and hook each extremity (but they are already hooked from what I understand?). If you don't want physics, maybe use Spline IK (a bit hard to set but pretty convenient)

Comment: for physics take a look here, except you won't use a plane but a cylinder: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196140/how-can-i-use-hooks-for-cloth-simulation

Comment: Yes the curve has two vertices, one at the bottom one at the top, and they're each hooked to an empty object. Does that prevent me from being able to use physics?

Comment: no, just use the method that is given in the link above. If you're not satisfied with the result, use Spline IK, it will allow you to animate the curve the way you want (except it won't be physics, you are the one that will create all the movements)

Comment: Thanks I have confidence in the examples you gave me